# gridview control and paging asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have a gridview which gets populated in the backend code. I am trying to implement paging now, but when I am trying my way, I am getting nothing.
Here is my piece of code:

```
public void generateTable()
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connString;
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ViewBusinessInfo", conn);
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.CommandTimeout = 2;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            gvAssociation.DataSource = rdr;
            gvAssociation.DataBind();
            gvAssociation.AllowPaging = true;
            gvAssociation.PageSize = 10;
            rdr.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            lblResult.Text = "No businesses found.";
            lblResult.Visible = true;
        }

    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Can anyone advice what am I doing wrong and I can't get the paging in the gridview?
Thx in advance, Laziale

Comment: For starters, you can probably change `catch` to `catch(Exception ex)` so you can see if you are actually getting an exception.  An empty `catch` block will hide your exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use paging with a DataReader. You should fill your data into a Dataset or a Datatable using a DataAdapter. Something like this:

```
 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("ViewBusinessInfo", conn);
 SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand))
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 myAdapter.Fill(dt);
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The allowPaging and pagesize property of the gridview can be added in the .aspx, where the gridview tag is present.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging"  AllowPaging="True" pagesize="10" runat="server" />
```

Additionally, to make the paging links work, you have to add the following code in the `gridview_PageIndexChanging` event of the gridview:

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: that was not the problem. The problem was that you cannot use a DataReader to populate a GridView if paging is enabled.

Comment: Yes you are right...it just skipped my mind. With DATAREADER as DATASOURCE, SERVER SIDE PAGING IS NOT ALLOWED. One will have to use DATAADAPTER-DATASET

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AllowPaging` and `PageSize` declaratively, or do so before you call `DataBind()`.

Comment: I am getting an error: The data source does not support server-side data paging