# Using SqlDataAdapter to page a SqlDataReader source

Tags: c#, gridview, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter, page-index-changed

This question seems to be common and I went through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215826/gridview-control-and-paging-asp-net) already.

Unfortunately, my page still isn't being paged. Here's what my code looks like in C#:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("(SELECT ......", Connection);
 SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 myAdapter.Fill(dt);

 command.Connection = connection;
 command.Connection.Open();

 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
 GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
 GridView1.PageSize = 15;

 command.Connection.Close();
 command.Connection.Dispose();
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, my paging doesn't show up. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting over 15 records with your select for sure? Also, set all of the Paging-related properties BEFORE the Databind() method is called.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I just had to set it before the databind(). Thanks!

Comment: Oh what's the difference between OnPageIndexChanging and OnPageIndexChanged?

Comment: PageIndexChanging occurs when one of the pager buttons is clicked, but before the GridView control handles the paging operation, while PageIndexChanged occurs when one of the pager buttons is clicked, but after the GridView control handles the paging operation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging.aspx and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanged.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set all of the Paging-related properties **before** the `Databind()` method is called. When you use *Custom Paging* you will have to handle the `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` event. You need to change the current PageIndex, and re-bind your `GridView` like this:

```
void bindGridview()
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("(SELECT ......", Connection);
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    myAdapter.Fill(dt);

    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Connection.Open();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
    GridView1.PageSize = 15;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();


    command.Connection.Close();
    command.Connection.Dispose();
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    bindGridview();
}
```

If you are also binding the GridView on `Page_Load`, do it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        bindGridview();
}
```

Comment: My first databind() was on pageLoad. However, when I add the if(!IsPostBack) into my GridView1_PageIndexChanging stuff, when I click to go to the next page of the gridview, nothing happens the first time. When I click again, then it goes to the next page. Without the if statement, it does so on the first click

Comment: Don't add the !IsPostBack into the PageIndexChanging, just in the Page_Load as I say in the answer :) I will update it with the event to avoid confusion :P

Comment: Ah ok great thanks! Out of curiosity, what does this do? Because it seems to work without the !IsPostBack in the pageload?

Comment: i doubt if the indexing will work without the `!IsPostback`...remove it and try it out...setting it will ensure your `GridView` loads only once during `pageload` and not all on `postbacks(eg. any click event is a postback`)..so when you click on the Page Numbers..its a `postback`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `PageIndexChanging` event of `GridView` to enable `paging`.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    bindGridview(); 
}
```